# Interação com array multidimensional em php

Tags: php, array

Tenho esses dados:

```
$answers = [
    'text-1626173297126' => [
        'Capítulo teste',
        'Juarez Neri Antônio Pereira',
        'CAVALEIROS DA LUZ'
    ],
    'text-1626173306001' =>
    [
        'Pedro Ds',
        'RenGraminhani',
        'CAR CESAR TANURI'
    ],
    'text-1626173476932' => [
        'dahve@gmail.com',
        'ren@etep.gov.br',
        'caranuri.com'
    ]
];
```

Eu preciso que a primeira coluna (text-1626173297126) fique na primeira coluna de uma tabela de html;
text-1626173306001, na segunda coluna;
text-1626173476932, na terceira;

Eu tentei fazer, algo como:

```php
foreach ($answers as $k => $value) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($value as $val) {

        echo '<td>', $val, '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

**Saída desejada**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quer seus dados exibidos em colunas trabalhe-os como se fossem uma tabela com [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php).

A função `array_column()` aceita um array multidimensional como entrada onde cada elemento(array ou objeto) representa uma linha em uma tabela, e cada sub elemento(elemento do elemento) representa uma coluna nessa tabela:

```
$answers = [
    'text-1626173297126' => [
        'Capítulo teste',
        'Juarez Neri Antônio Pereira',
        'CAVALEIROS DA LUZ'
    ],
    'text-1626173306001' =>
    [
        'Pedro Ds',
        'RenGraminhani',
        'CAR CESAR TANURI'
    ],
    'text-1626173476932' => [
        'dahve@gmail.com',
        'ren@etep.gov.br',
        'caranuri.com'
    ]
];

foreach (range(0, count($answers) - 1) as $idx) {   //Itera pelos índices das linhas da tabela.
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach (array_column($answers, $idx) as $val){  //Itera pelas colunas dessa linha.
    echo '<td>', $val, '</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/tabela#index.php)</sup>

Resultando em:

```html
<!--HTML foi formatado e adaptado para facilitar a exibição-->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Capítulo teste</td>
    <td>Pedro Ds</td>
    <td>dahve@gmail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Juarez Neri Antônio Pereira</td>
    <td>RenGraminhani</td>
    <td>ren@etep.gov.br</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CAVALEIROS DA LUZ</td>
    <td>CAR CESAR TANURI</td>
    <td>caranuri.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```